# How can I read Excel data with Apache Beam Python pipeline? I get an unsupported operand error

Tags: python, excel, google-cloud-storage, pipeline, apache-beam

I'm trying to read an Excel file in my cloud storage bucket with Apache Beam Python pipeline, but it is not working. I tried to read with Pandas but I can't use the data in Pcollection.

Do you know a way to do that?

```
def read_data_from_excel_file():
  bucket_name = "nidec-ga-transient"
  blob_name = "ConcessoesERestricoes.xlsx"

  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
  blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

  data_bytes = blob.download_as_bytes()

  df = pd.read_excel(data_bytes, 'Lista de Gargalos')
  return df

Pipeline = (
  pipeline_load_data
    | "Importar Dados CloudStorage" >> read_data_from_excel_file()
  # | "Write_to_BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
  #                            tabela,
  #                            schema=table_schema,
  #                            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
  #                            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
  #                            custom_gcs_temp_location = 'gs://ddc-test-262213-staging/henrique.klock@dojo.technology/temp' )
 )
```

I got this error when I ran the code:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'str' and 'NoneType'

Answer (score 0):

This can get you an idea, (i haven't tried this code in my system)
Reading Excel data in an Apache Beam Python pipeline can be achieved using the apache_beam.io.fileio module. This module provides functionality to read files in a parallel and distributed manner.

```
def read_data_from_excel_file(file_pattern):
    def process_excel_file(element):
        file_name = element.metadata.path
        df = pd.read_excel(file_name, 'Lista de Gargalos')
        return df.values.tolist()

    return (
        beam
        | "MatchFiles" >> beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles(file_pattern)
        | "ReadMatches" >> beam.io.fileio.ReadMatches()
        | "ProcessExcelFile" >> beam.Map(process_excel_file)
    )

file_pattern = "gs://nidec-ga-transient/ConcessoesERestricoes.xlsx"
pipeline = beam.Pipeline()

(
    pipeline
    | "Importar Dados CloudStorage" >> read_data_from_excel_file(file_pattern)
    | "DoSomething" >> beam.Map(print)
    # Add more transformations as needed
)

pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Actually with this code I got the follow error: TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable. I could read with other code, I will post here

Comment: `def process_excel_file(element):
    file_name = element.metadata.path
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name, 'Lista de Gargalos')
    df = df.to_dict()
    return df

pipeline_load_data = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
file_path = "gs://nidec-ga-transient/ConcessoesERestricoes.xlsx"

Pipeline = (
  pipeline_load_data
    | "Importar Dados Cloud Storage" >> beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles(file_path)
    | "ReadMatches" >> beam.io.fileio.ReadMatches()
    | "ProcessExcelFile" >> beam.Map(process_excel_file)
 )
pipeline_load_data.run().wait_until_finish()`

Comment: I just wrote the code and didn't try it on my system. You can get the idea with this. @HenriqueKlock